# CANVAS: SHMUP background drawing

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

```
bgY += ( enemySpeed + heroSpeed ) / 2;
ctx.drawImage( bg, bgX, bgY - gameHeight );
ctx.drawImage( bg, bgX, bgY );
if( bgY > gameHeight )
{
    bgY = 0;
}
```

I'm using the code above to draw a background on my canvas.

It works well, except for a small lag whenever the new image is drawn. Just before it's drawn, the player can see how the background does not have an image for a second at the top. ( That's not my main problem, but you can help with that too )

Anyways, now for the main problem:

I'm not sure, but I think that when images are moved below the canvas, they're not actually removed.. Isn't that going to slow the game down / give bad performance after a while?

Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: What do you mean by "images are moved below the canvas" or by "they're not actually removed"?

Comment: The first line of code, " bgY += ( enemySpeed + heroSpeed ) / 2; " means that the bgY point is moved downwards, which means that when the new background images are drawn, they are lower than before. When the point goes below the canvas, I set the bgY to 0, which means that it starts drawing from the top again. But the images that are below the canvas ( those that have been already drawn ) are, afaik, still below the canvas, they just can't be seen.

Comment: Ah, now I see. Drawing the images is optimized (for any reasonable implementation of canvas) such that images are clipped with respect to canvas boundaries before drawing. This has a tiny effect on performance but nothing you see (and hardly even measure).

Comment: So that means that the images that would be below the canvas's bottom, are actually 'cropped' away?

Comment: Images outside the canvas are cropped, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your first question: the if-statement should be right before the calls to `drawImage` but not after. You may also replace it by a modulo operation which should be save for all relevant cases.

```
bgY += ( enemySpeed + heroSpeed ) / 2;
bgY %= gameHeight;
ctx.drawImage( bg, bgX, bgY - gameHeight );
ctx.drawImage( bg, bgX, bgY );
```

Comment: Yeah, that helps with the temporary transparency. Thanks.